# AutoWheel offset

Tags: tires

I have a 2016 rogue with 17 inch wheel
I found a set of alloy wheel from a 2015
pathfinder,using a 225-60-18 inch tire everything fit perfect no issue with fender
or brake or fender clearance,until I found
out about wheel offset pathfinder has 50mm
rogue 36mm did I make a big mistake,I can’t
return the wheels is my car safe to use
Ron

Comment: If necessary sell them second-hand, see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/17877/10976

Comment: Have you measured clearances all around, including at full left/ right turns and at full shock travel?  Note a floor jack will help you see where things are going to be tight at full shock travel.